# Short S.M.A.R.T test completes successfully with gnome-disk, but smartctl reports a read failure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, linux-mint, smart

I acquired an used 1Tb Western Digital hard drive and I want to check its health status under Linux Mint 18.2.

I checked its S.M.A.R.T health status and everything is reported as OK. `gnome-disk` reports only one bad sector.

I ran a short test with `gnome-disk` and it completed successfully.

I also tried to run a short test with `smartctl` with the `smartctl /dev/sdc -t short` command, and it reports a read failure (reads the command output bellow):

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.8.0-53-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8065         -
# 2  Conveyance captive  Interrupted (host reset)      90%      8065         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      8065         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8064         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      8064         125259637
# 6  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      8064         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8064         -
```

Then I tried to run an extended test with `gnome-disk`, and this time it didn't complete successfully, it failed at 90%.

So I ran an extended test using `smartctl` using the `sudo smartctl /dev/sdc -t long -C` command, and here is the selftest log:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.8.0-53-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      8065         -
# 2  Conveyance captive  Interrupted (host reset)      90%      8065         -
# 3  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      8065         -
# 4  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      8065         -
# 5  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      8065         -
# 6  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      8065         -
# 7  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      8065         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8065         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8065         -
#10  Conveyance captive  Interrupted (host reset)      90%      8065         -
#11  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      8065         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8064         -
#13  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      8064         125259637
#14  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      8064         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8064         -
```

Is the hard drive still reliable? Is this failure benign? How should I read `smartctl` logs in future cases?

Comment: I would *highly* recommend using Seagate's SeaTools software to get a definitive diagnosis on this.  The reason for this is because Seagate uses SMART in a proprietary way and SeaTools is probably the only software that can properly interpret all SMART data and self-test results. Burn a bootable CD/DVD/USB-KEY from this ISO, boot your PC to SeaTools and do a full test: http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/support-content/downloads/seatools/_shared/downloads/SeaToolsDOS223ALL.ISO